# How do I make this array of params in a parent param in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, parameters

This is my call as it is :

```
$(this.form).attr("action",$(this.form).attr("action") + '?' + $("#sortable").sortable('serialize') + "&foo[]=bar");
```

Which creates this :

```
importance[]=1&importance[]=2&importance[]=3
```

My problem is is that I want these params to be apart of `card_signup`

So that in `card_signup`, I would have `importance[1, 2, 3]`

How can I alter my original call so that the `importance` params will appear within the card_signup param?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the serialized return to do that.

You could also modify this code to save having to read the attribute twice in your code.

```
 $(this.form).attr("action", function(index, action) {
    var values = [],
        getKey;

    $("#sortable").sortable('serialize').replace(/(\w+?)\[]=(\d+?)/g, function(all, key, number) {
        values.push(number);
        getKey = key;
    });

    var cardSignupGetParams = 'card_signup=' + getKey + '[' + values.join(', ') + ']';
    return action + '?' + cardSignupGetParams + "&foo[]=bar";
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/U2Bd2/).

Comment: You'll have to excuse my daftness. The reason I have the `&foo[]=bar` at the end is because for some reason, my params were returning as `importance["1","2","3.json"], and to separate the `.json`, I just added false param at the end. Completely horrible coding practice.

Comment: I'm getting a `missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error] return action + '?' + cardSignupGetParams);` in jquery 1.3.2.. But nevertheless, thank you so much alex. I can't even tell you how much this helps!

Comment: FYI, That 2nd comment's error is caused by an additional parentheses.

Comment: @Trip Yes, I have fixed that up now :) See live example on fiddle too.